# 'outofmemoryerror' in the getView() from custom BaseAdapter

Tags: android, out-of-memory, baseadapter, getview

I have an Activity with a grid layout where display images from SD folders. When I select a folder, all images are added to a String list (clean when folder is changed), and images construction is in getView() method, using these strings from the list.

It works properly for 5 or 6 times (images from folder are displayed), but then I change the folder and I get an 'outofmemoryerror' in the getView() from the custom BaseAdapter (see code line), but I don't understand my leak problem...

Images are 30-100 kB each one.

This is the code:

```
private ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

...

public void add(String path) {
    itemList.add(path); 
}

public void clean() {
    itemList.clear();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{   
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        int iImageSize = mContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.grid_image_size);
        int iImagePadding = mContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.grid_image_padding);

        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(iImageSize, iImageSize));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(iImagePadding,iImagePadding,iImagePadding,iImagePadding);
    } 
    else
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;

    String sImagePath = itemList.get(position);
    imageView.setTag(sImagePath);
    imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(sImagePath)); // Crash HERE

    return imageView;
}
```

Trace Log:

04-21 10:10:50.697: E/art(1665): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1000012 byte allocation with 732188 free bytes and 715KB until OOM"

04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665): Process: com.apps.apppictos, PID: 1665
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1000012 byte allocation with 732188 free bytes and 715KB until OOM
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:635)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:611)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:391)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:417)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromPath(Drawable.java:1143)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:782)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:429)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at com.apps.apppictos.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:93)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1433)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:361)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:302)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.GridView.fillSpecific(GridView.java:582)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1287)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
04-21 10:11:31.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
04-21 10:11:39.427: I/art(1665): Clamp target GC heap from 49MB to 48MB

Comment: It would be better if you can paste the stack trace logs as well..

Comment: The images are to big to display a lot of them. Try to resize them down first.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, traces added. I realized that the crash happens when I select a folder with 40 images (8kB to 20 kB), is it too much memory??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using images may cause outOfMemory on your device. The allocated memory differs from device to device.

Two approaches:

1. Use LruCache class to optimize memory usage and caching

   [http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
2. Use Picasso a powerful image downloading and caching library for Android

   http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Thanks a lot Kamal, I will try LruCache, hope it works!

Answer (score -1):

This also happens when someone inflate a CustomView like:

`inflate(getContext, R.layout.my_custom_view_layout, this)`

instead of:

`inflate(getContext, R.layout.my_custom_view_layout, null)`